# Prove that either $(2^{10500} + 15)$ or $(2^{10500} + 16)$ is not a perfect square.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that either $(2^{10500} + 15)$ or $(2^{10500} + 16)$ is not a perfect
square.

how should I solve this problem? what is the idea for solving this kind of problems?

Thank you so much

Comment: Hint: you don't need to compute anything except $2^{10500} > 0$.

Comment: when $a^2-b^2=1?$

Comment: *Hint*: both of them are between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ for some $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't this say "neither/nor" rather than "either/or" ?

Comment: It is clearly a problem that is designed to intimidate you, so that you miss the absolutely simple solution. You solve this by ignoring the homungous numbers that are intended to frighten you and turn your brain into a mush, and realise that the only two consecutive perfect squares are 0^2 and 1^2.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  What is the next perfect square above $2^{10500}$?  How does that compare to the numbers you're given?

Answer (score 0):

Find square root of $2^{10500}$:
$$(2^{10500})^\frac12=2^{10500\times\frac12}=2^{5250}$$
and the next square is
$$(2^{5250}+1)^2=2^{10500}+2^{5251}+1$$
The difference between these $2$ squares is
$$2^{10500}+2^{5251}+1-2^{10500}=2^{5251}+1$$
$2^{5251}+1$ is way bigger than $15$ or $16$

**Edit:** This proves none of them are perfect squares. The difference between the $2$ numbers you have given us is only $1$ and **no 2 perfect squares except 0 and 1 have a difference of 1**.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two squares $n^2$ and $(n + a)^2$ is $2an + a^2$.

Say they are both squares, $n^2 = 2^{10500} + 15$ and $(n+a)^2 = 2^{10500} + 16$. Taking their difference, $1 = 2an + a^2$. But $n$ is huge and $a^2$ is positive, so that's absurd.